# I can't open jupyter notebook from anaconda prompt. This is what I am seeing after I try to open it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQb5K.jpg

How do I get this to work? I am an absolute beginner using the command prompt.

Comment: "This is what I am seeing..." You seem to have missed some important details from your question.

Comment: Have you tried googling the traceback error? Try 'pip install --upgrade pyzmq' or reinstalling Python for starters.